# Proving that: $f(t)\le \max\left(1,\frac{t}{s}\right)f(s)$ for concave function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, inequality, convex-analysis

Assume $f : (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a continuous and concave function

> Then prove that $f$ is nondecreasing and that $t\mapsto t^{-1}f(t)$ is a non-increasing function
>
> and conclude that: for any $s,t>0$, we have
> $$f(t)\le \max\left(1,\frac{t}{s}\right)f(s)$$

**My attempt:** for $0<s<t$ then I have $t^{-1}f(t)\le s^{-1}f(s)$. since $t\mapsto t^{-1}f(t)$ is a non-increasing.  Therefore, $$f(t)\le \max\left(1,\frac{t}{s}\right)f(s)$$
Now what if $0<t<s$ then we have $$f(t)\le f(s) \le \max\left(1,\frac{t}{s}\right)f(s)$$ since $t\mapsto f(t)$ is a non-decreasing.

> **Question**:Any idea on how to prove the monotonicity??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 < x < y < z$ the concavity condition for $f$ is
$$ \tag{*}
 f(y) \ge \frac{z-y}{z-x} \, f(x) + \frac{y-x}{z-x} \, f(z)
$$

First, using $f(z) > 0$ in $(*)$ implies
$$
f(y) \ge \frac{z-y}{z-x} \, f(x) \, 
$$
for all $z > y$, and taking the limit $z \to \infty$ it follows
that $f(y) \ge f(x)$, i.e. $f(t)$ is non-decreasing.

Next, using $f(x) > 0$ in $(*)$ implies
$$
 \frac{f(y)}{y-x} \ge \frac{f(z)}{z-x}
$$
for $0 < x < y$, and taking the limit $x \to 0$ gives
$ 
\frac{f(y)}{y} \ge \frac{f(z)}{z}
$,
i.e. $f(t)/t$ is non-increasing.

Answer (score 1):

1) $f$ is non decreasing.

Assume, by contradiction, that there exist $0<a<b$ such that $f(a) > f(b)$.
Since $f$ is concave we have that
$$
f(x) \leq f(b) + \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\, (x-b),
\qquad \forall x \geq b,
$$
hence, by comparison, $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = -\infty$, a contradiction.

2) $t \mapsto f(t)/t$ is non increasing in $(0,+\infty)$.

Since $f > 0$ and $f$ is non decreasing, there exists
$$
f(0) := \lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) \geq 0.
$$
Let $0 < s < t$ and let $\lambda := s/t \in (0,1)$. Using again the concavity of $f$:
$$
f(s) = f((1-\lambda)0 + \lambda t) \geq (1-\lambda) f(0) + \lambda f(t)
\geq \lambda f(t) = \frac{s}{t}\, f(t),
$$
i.e. $f(s) / s \geq f(t) / t$.